# How do you call a scale that starts at $∞$, has $1/n$ divisions and tends to $0$?

Tags: definition, graphing-functions, infinity

#### A linear scale

- $2n$ divisions: `0     2     4     6     8`

#### Logarithmic scales

- $10^n$ divisions: `1    10    100  1000  10000`
- Lin-Log Plot:

[image: Lin-Log graph]

#### What is the name of this scale?

- $\dfrac1n$ divisions: `∞   1.00  0.50  0.33  0.25`
- Focus distance scale on a lens:

[image]

Comment: I suppose you can call it "the $1/x$-scale".

Comment: I would guess "reciprocal scale". It brings up some relevant-looking hits on Google at least.